# Why DSolve gives the error "Arguments should be ordered consistently" on this PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

This problem is strange. Mathematica is able to solve this PDE with no error

```
ClearAll[x,y,u];
pde=u[x,y]*(x+y)*D[u[x,y],x]+u[x,y]*(x-y)*D[u[x,y],y]==x^2+y^2;
ic=u[x,2*x]==0;
DSolve[{pde,ic},u[x,y],{x,y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similar one, no error

```
ClearAll[x, y, u];
pde = x*D[u[x, y], x] + y*D[u[x, y], y] == x*Exp[-u[x, y]];
ic = u[x, x^2] == 0;
DSolve[{pde, ic}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this similar one, it gives error

```
ClearAll[x, y, u];
pde = (y - u[x, y])*D[u[x, y], x] + (u[x, y] - x)*D[u[x, y], y] == x - y;
ic = u[x, 1/x] == 0;
DSolve[{pde, ic}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
```

This error

```
DSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.
```

What is the difference here? Why it works sometimes? What is wrong with the order is the third example?

Mathematica 12 on windows 10.

Comment: You're trying to solve a non-linear equation using `DSolve`. This equation may not have a well known solution.

Comment: @AlexTrounev This is an example from textbook, and the solution is given there and the steps to obtain it. The solution is  $u(x,y)=\frac{1- x y}{x+y}$

Comment: @Nasser It looks as a bug for me.

Comment: @Nasser You're right, there is an exact solution. But this does not mean that it is in the Mathematica  database. See https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1610701